# PHP Diff Partial Datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to subtract the time difference between the current datetime, and a time stated in my database. The datetimes current format is yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss, however for this specific case i just want to subtract the time and not the date so i only want hh:mm:ss to be calculated and then stored into a different variable i can use and format how i want. Is it possible to take a full datetime, break it apart and do a diff on it? I think this is kind of confusing so ask if you need clarification. Here's what i've tried thus far:

```
<?php
//The time in the database
$classTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '0000-00-00 18:30:00');

$timein = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Detroit'));
$timein->getTimestamp();
$timeout = $classTime;
$totaltime = $timeout->diff($timein);
$totaltime = $totaltime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$totaltime = date('0000:00:00 H:i:s', strtotime($totaltime));
//I create a new date because i'm storing this time into the database, which can't be done with a datetime.

//FORMAT TIMES
$timein = $timein->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$timeout = $timeout->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "Time in " . $timein . " Time Out " . $timeout . " Total Time " . $totaltime;
?>
```

This current output returns:

```
Time in 2013-04-02 14:05:32 Time Out -0001-11-30 18:30:00 Total Time 0000:00:00 00:00:00
```

But i want it to return something like:

```
Time in 2013-04-02 14:05:32 Time Out -0000-00-00 18:30:00 Total Time 0000:00:00 03:30:00
```

Comment: Are you assuming the time out is always the same date? Why not just included the date?

Comment: unfortunately it's not, it depends on the class that's pulled from the database, i only did it this way to simply things, sorry if this confused matters more.

Comment: If you are working with just the 'time' portion, `DateTime` can't calculate it correctly.  Time is based of time stamps with 0 being Jan 1 1970 UTC (if I remember correctly), so anything left after a calculation only using the hours/min/sec of a stamp will give the number of seconds difference, so from there you'd have to calculate that in to hours:min:sec by hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP find difference between two datetimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688775/php-find-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear and I spent quite a bit of time answering the wrong question until I took a careful look at your code to see what you actually wanted.

As far as I understand it you store the finishing time of a lesson in your database as a MySql Datetime type and you want to find the time remaining between `now` and the time the lesson ends.

I'll ignore timezones for the purpose of this answer.

You start with

```
$classTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '0000-00-00 18:30:00');
```

To do a meaningful time comparison, the date portion of $classTime needs to be set to today:-

```
$timeIn = new DateTime();

$year = (int)$timeIn->format('Y');
$month  = (int)$timeIn->format('m');
$day = (int)$timeIn->format('d');

$classTime->setDate($year, $month, $day);
```

You can then do the comparison:-

```
$diff = $timeIn->diff($classTime);
```

$diff is now an instance of [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

We can now echo out the information:-

```
$start = $timeIn->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end = $classTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$duration = $diff->format("%Hh, %Im, %Ss");
echo "Time in: $start, Time out: $end, Duration: $duration";
```

Which at the time I ran the code, gave the following output:-

```
Time in: 2013-04-05 13:22:54, Time out: 2013-04-05 18:30:00, Duration: 05h, 07m, 06s
```