# How To Check If A Value is increasing or has increased - PHP

Tags: php, date

i am writing a script that checks for increase in date to know whether or not to add a value to an existing variable. 
Though i have been able to get some help here, it still appears i'm stuck with checking if the day has increased.

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
 $now = time(); // or your date as well
 $your_date = strtotime("2018-09-05");
 $datediff = $now - $your_date;

 $alreadySpentDays = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

 $userEarnings = 0;

 // i want to be able to check if the day has increased and if it has i want to be able to add $10 to userEarning variable daily
?>
<p><?=$userEarnings?></p>
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're running into? It looks like the code you have will roughly tell you if a day has gone by (you may want to use `floor` instead of `round`). This might also be a good opportunity (and reason) to switch to using PHP's [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) library. Then you can take advantage of things like the `diff` method. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102603/get-a-php-datetime-difference-in-days-considering-midnight-as-a-day-change) might help ease you into `DateTime`.

Comment: Actually, getting the days is not the issue, my problem is with knowing when it increases and adding $10 to user daily earning

Comment: `echo '$'.number_format(date('G') * (10 / 24), 2).' earned today!';` [1](https://3v4l.org/M4TNX) then cron job it at a 00:00 to apply..

Comment: @courage Where are you storing the user's daily earnings? Is it possible to also store the last date that the user's earnings were evaluated (so that you can see how many days worth of money they've earned since then)? Or do you store the date that the user first began earning daily, so that you can simply say get the difference in days between now and that start date, and multiply it by $10?

Comment: I did store the registration date and get the difference between then and the current date

Comment: and i am not multiplying it by 10, i simply want to add $10 to user earnings everyday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in calculating it each day, just do the calculation when needed.
$start_date is the date you want to start counting from, where the earning is 0.
Then just calculate the number of days that has passed by and multiply with 10.

```
$now = time(); // or your date as well
$start_date = strtotime("2018-09-04");
$datediff = $now - $start_date;

$alreadySpentDays = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
echo $alreadySpentDays * 10; // 20, since it's two days of earnings (september 4 and 5)
```

Comment: Perfect thinking, wonderful answer. u just solved the whole problem

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime::diff (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$userEarnings = 0;
$now = new DateTime(); //now
$your_date = new DateTime("2010-09-05");

$diff = $now->diff($your_date);

if ($diff->days > 0) {
    $userEarnings += 10;
}
```

Comment: that line does it only once and refuses to do it (add $10) again the next day

Comment: Look into crons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron and have your script executed once every day and it will add $10 every time it runs.

Comment: i love the idea. lemme try