# PHP time different

Tags: php

Problem: 
The output is wrong despite that in DB is correct (timestamp)

Screenshot of DB: http://prntscr.com/mjftzn

The code is the output

```
    $dbDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // Database date
    $endDate =  strtotime("".$query['duedate']."");    // current time
    $diff = $endDate - $dbDate; /// diffrence
     $days = intval(intval($diff) / (3600*24));
$newDays = $days < 0 ? 'EXPIRED' : $days;
```

Result of code: http://prntscr.com/mjfw4t

Expected: 14 day remaining instead of expired, if -1 it will show expired

Comment: Have you checked what `$query['duedate']` has when you do this calculation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102603/get-a-php-datetime-difference-in-days-considering-midnight-as-a-day-change

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your code works fine. https://3v4l.org/pl096

Comment: @Nick http://prntscr.com/mjg2e2 , this is what i get (without showing expired)

Comment: You are probably fetching the wrong dates then.

Comment: @VoxVola I think you should refer to Nigel's comment then...

Comment: @Nick http://prntscr.com/mjg721 ,this is the result

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can calculate difference between two dates:

```
$date1 = "2007-03-24";
$date2 = "2009-06-26";

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));


printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

Now implement it with your own logic.

Comment: Jsus, so many calculations, why not use the `DateTime` library?

Comment: I like `maths`.

Comment: CPU's too, people paying for EC2 instances not so much though.

Answer (score 0):

When working with dates and time in PHP a lot of what you want to do is handled by [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) library. An extension to this that I have ended up using a lot is [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) which provides a lot of functions to calculate [differences](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference), intervals and also turn it into human-readable form etc.

Using Carbon you could write something like this.

```
$days    = Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->diffInDays(Carbon::parse($query['duedate']));
$newDays = $days < 0 ? 'EXPIRED' : $days;
```

But since you seem to just use the current time as the "database date" you could use `Carbon::now()` instead of parsing the string provided by `date()` into a Carbon object.

Comment: @treyBake: For seemingly simple things I tend to want to help people find the answer, read and understand it :). Updated with a small piece of code though. Although the initial code provided seems a bit strange since the op's "database date" seems to be the current time. But op probably knows how the logic of the system is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Database. Use something like

```
SELECT duedate>NOW() as expired;
```