# How to calculate time difference?

Tags: php, datetime, date-difference

i have 2 type of time values are 2015-09-25 11:52:22 and 2015-09-25 01:06:57. i using date different function in php. my code as

```
$date_a = new DateTime($from_time);
$date_b = new DateTime($to_time);
$interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);

echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

Out put gives 10:45:25.how can calculated time diff??

2015-09-25 11:52:22 is AM and 2015-09-25 01:06:57 is PM that time only i got look like otherwise coming correct

Comment: but 10:45:25 IS the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP find difference between two datetimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688775/php-find-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Comment: 2015-09-25 11:52:22 is AM and 2015-09-25 01:06:57 is PM that time only i got look like otherwise coming correct

Answer (score 1):

The 'diff' method applies to a DateTime Object..

```
$from_time = '2015-09-25 11:52:22';
$to_time   = '2015-09-25 01:06:57';

  $date_a = new DateTime($from_time);
  $date_b = new DateTime($to_time);
//$interval =     date_diff($date_a,$date_b);
  $interval = $date_a->diff($date_b);
  echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');

// 10:45:25
```

Comment: i Got Error Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: So we need to store the date is 24hours format right