# How to get timespan values Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, timestamp, unix-timestamp, timespan

I am trying to get the values from `timespan()` function in Code Igniter. I have one problem, how can I know whether each of the date format is displayed? For example in regards with the codes below, one timespan might be `2 Months, 6 Days, 13 Hours, 14 Minutes` which would have 4 elements but another might be `2 Months, 1 Week, 3 Days, 4 Hours, 39 Minutes` which has 5 elements. If do the `preg_replace` then I won't know which are the months or weeks or days etc.

So how do I find out if it is the week or days or hours etc? Because I want to convert the values into cycles like `39mins/1440mins` would be 0.0270833 days, then I will calculate for the hours days weeks months and years and add all of them together

```
// Hold Cycle Time Conversion

foreach($results as $key => $values)
{
    // Convert mysql timestamp to unix
    $remove = array('-', ':', ' ');
    $hold_timestamp = mysql_to_unix( str_replace( $remove, '', $values['hold_date'] ) );

    // Get timespan
    $hold_timestamp = timespan($hold_timestamp);

    // Explode into arrays
    $timestamp_format = explode(',', $hold_timestamp);

    // Check each array to get value
    foreach($timestamp_format as $ts)
    {
        $separated_stamp = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $ts);

        /*** Stuck here, incomplete ***/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to abandon that logic and use PHP's [Date Time class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead. Got some help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688775/php-find-difference-between-two-datetimes) as well. Not sure if it's the best way but it's what I've found.

```
// Hold Cycle Time Conversion

foreach($results as $key => $values)
{
    // Declare timestamps
    $last = new DateTime( $values['hold_date'] );
    $now = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d h:i:s', time() )) ; 

    // Find difference
    $interval = $last->diff($now);

    // Store in variable to be used for calculation etc
    $years = (int)$interval->format('%Y');
    $months = (int)$interval->format('%m');
    $days = (int)$interval->format('%d');
    $hours = (int)$interval->format('%H');
    $minutes = (int)$interval->format('%i');
}
```