# php timer countdown help on this code

Tags: php

have this count php countdown code i found during my searching on google this is good how ever my code i added to this  which is `$expire_date`  shows **dec 14** in this format only no time with it.

how do i check if the date is passed and expired.
i want it to show like this

if   xxxxx date then counting down
else
expired days :0

```
$dt_end = new DateTime($expire_date);
$remain = $dt_end->diff(new DateTime());
echo $remain->d . ' days and ' . $remain->h . ' hours';
```

Comment: see first comment here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688775/php-find-difference-between-two-datetimes

Comment: @Armen `date()` does not equal `DateTime`...

Comment: @arkascha check then answer of that question

Comment: @Armen `first comment` does not equal `first answer`... :-) Sorry, but I check the first comment, as you suggested. That is about `date()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED

Try this (based on Armen suggested post)

```
<?php
    $expire_date = "dec 14";   //you can change this date
    $datetime1 = new DateTime();  
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($expire_date);

    if($datetime2 >= $datetime1) { 
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2); 
        $remaining_days = $interval->format('%a');
        $remaning_hours = $interval->format('%h');
        $remaning_minutes = $interval->format('%m');
        $remaning_seconds = $interval->format('%s');
        echo 'Now is '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').'<br>';
        echo 'To '.$expire_date.' remains ';        
        echo $remaining_days. ' days, '.$remaning_hours.' hours, '.$remaning_minutes.' minutes, '.$remaning_seconds.' seconds.';
    } else {
        echo 'Time expired';
    };
?>
```

I've updated the code with your last requests. Try it now... it will stamp something like:

> It is Friday 11th of December 2015 06:08:02 PM
>
> To dec 14 remains 2 days, 5 hours, 0 minutes, 58 seconds.

---

**Including a live countdown**

To include a live countdown we could use jQuery and a script born to do that. It's very simple, you have just to include jQuery library in your code and then the jQuery library jquery.countdown.min.js and little more.

You could download that library from here:
http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/
then you have upload it in the same folder of your page on your webserver.

Here the updated code of your page:

```
    <?php
    $expire_date = "dec 25";   //you can change this date
    $datetime1 = new DateTime();  
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($expire_date);

    $formatted_date = $datetime2->format('Y-m-d'); // we need to pass a well formatted expire date to jQuery


    if($datetime2 >= $datetime1) { 
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2); 
        $remaining_days = $interval->format('%a');
        $remaining_hours = $interval->format('%h');
        $remaining_minutes = $interval->format('%m');
        $remaining_seconds = $interval->format('%s');
        echo 'Now is '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').'<br>';

        echo 'To Christmas '.$expire_date.' remains ';        
        echo $remaining_days. ' days, '.$remaining_hours.' hours, '.$remaining_minutes.' minutes, '.$remaining_seconds.' seconds.';
        ?>


        <h2>To Christmas <span id="getting-started"></span></h2> <!-- that is the container of the countdown in your page, jQuery will populate it -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- copy this line as it is, it's load jQuery library from google repository -->
        <script src="jquery.countdown.min.js"></script> <!-- here you have to load the countdown library, modify your path in case you'll put that library in a subfolder -->

        <!-- that's our jQuery script -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
                var dateVar = "<?php echo $formatted_date;?>";
                var expire_date=new Date(dateVar);

                $('#getting-started').countdown(expire_date, function(event) {
                    $(this).html(event.strftime('%w weeks %d days %H:%M:%S'));
                });
        </script>

<?php
    } else {
        echo 'Time expired';
    };
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> Now is Wednesday 16th of December 2015 07:50:52 AM
>
> To Christmas dec 25 remains 8 days, 16 hours, 0 minutes, 8 seconds.  <-- static text
>
> **To Christmas 01 weeks 01 days 17:08:48** <-- live countdown

Hoping to be helpful. :)

Comment: first of all i want to say thats for the effort you made to give me this peace of code .   i want to say is it possible to add code to check current month then   calculate   dec 14th  and then se how many days left ,      because i have some old post that has expired with the dates on them jul 4  ,june xx

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand your request, could you provide a clear example of what you need.

Comment: for example my code $expire_date dec 18     and todays date is   12/11/2015      so calculate remaining days till it reaches   18th with min/hours if possible wil be nice

Comment: @SarahLee try the script now and in case it's ok please accept the answer.

Comment: correct i seen your post above now let me try am happy you understood what i needed thanks and let me try gianca cheers.

Comment: @SarahLee I'm happy to help, but don't forget to vote the answer and to flag it like accepted, it could help someone else in future.

Comment: is it possible to add live counter rather then showing static time ? i mean when page loads show time counting down ?

Comment: Yes of course, but I'll use jQuery to do that. 'll update the first answer.