# PHP - MySQL Substract Different Time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a report I built but the problem is the subtract time in the database.

as

```
$intime= "02:00:00";
$outtime= "03:25:50";
```

Output will be  `01:25:50`

So my question is how can I take an action in PHP (string of mysql format time)

Comment: Please share if you have tried something ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15688824/2815635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class:

```
$a = new DateTime('02:00:00');
$b = new DateTime('03:25:50');
echo $a->diff($b)->format("%H:%I:%S");  // 01:25:50
```

Comment: thanks trincot
it's nice...

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for having accepted ;)