# PHP date_diff DateInterval could not be converted

Tags: php, datetime, date-math

I am having a heck of a time trying to find the difference between two dates. I am getting a date out of a database and trying to compare it with the current date and time.

What I need is the number of hours between the two dates. If I format the date_diff as "%h%", I am only getting the subtracted hours between the hours, not the total time like between 2:00pm three days ago and 3:00pm today. With "%h" this only give me the result 1 hour.

With the code below, I am getting the error "Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string" when trying to echo $SinceLastUpdate. I have tried all kinds of formatting of the dates and I am going nuts on this one.

Here is my current code:

```
//Database stuff
$SqLiteSqlStr = "SELECT Max(END_TIME) AS LAST_UPDATE FROM DATA_LOAD_LOG";   
PDO_Connect("sqlite:$SqLiteDB");
$results = PDO_FetchAll($SqLiteSqlStr);
foreach ($results as $row) { $DataUpdated = $row["LAST_UPDATE"];}

//Make some kind of attempt to find out how old the data is
$TodaysDate = new DateTime("now");
$SinceLastUpdate = date_diff(new DateTime($DataUpdated), $TodaysDate );
echo "<br>TodaysDate " . date_format($TodaysDate,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo "<br>DataUpdated " . $DataUpdated;
echo "<br>SinceLastUpdate " . $SinceLastUpdate;
```

Right now, I don't care if the difference is in seconds, minutes or hours, I just need some kind of accurate number I can work with. 
What I am trying to do is check how old the data is. If it is more than three days old (72 hours), then I need to run my process to update the data.

Any help is going to be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP find difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688775/php-find-difference-between-two-datetimes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you use just `%h` modifier.

Information in `DateInterval` stored not like total amount of hours between dates, but amounts of all types of date/time.

So, if you compare in your example

> time like between 2:00pm three days ago and 3:00pm today

you get one hour with `%h`, yes. But you also get **3 days** with `%d` modifier.

So, I suppose, you just need to check:

```
$days = $SinceLastUpdate->format('%d');
if ($days < 3) { /* do stuff */ }
```

But in more simple way you can just compare timestamps - current and `$DataUpdated`, if difference is greater than 3 days (3 * 86400) - do something:

```
$TodaysDate = new DateTime("now");
$du = new DateTime($DataUpdated);
if ($du->format('U') - $TodaysDate->format('U') > (86400 * 3)) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```