# Trying to understand the DateTime::diff() function

Tags: php

the result of the difference between two dates does it well if they are whole hours but without minutes it does not show me the correct data.**THE CODE:**

```
$r=strtr($marcacion->marcacion, '/', '-');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime($r));
$dates = new DateTime($date);
$dteDiff  = $temporal->diff($dates);
```

the variable $temporal is the same case, just is the previous value.
**AND THE RESULT:**

1. ID: 310 value temporal: 21-02-2017 07:30:00 AM ---
          value dates: 21-02-2017 13:03:00 PM        total time : 05:33 **(should be 06:33)**
2. ID: 310 value temporal: 23-02-2017 07:34:00 AM ---
          value dates: 23-02-2017 13:06:00 PM        total time : 05:32
3. ID: 316 value temporal: 14-02-2017 13:15:00 PM ---
          value dates: 14-02-2017 17:15:00 PM        total time : 04:00

Comment: Which result are you concerned about?

Comment: 13:03:00 PM? Which is not true. Something is wrong.

Comment: Check [PHP find difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15688824/3226121)

Comment: @wedstrom the total of hours and minutes in the case 1, the total shoulbe : 6:33

Comment: 13:03:00 PM? military format 24 hours @RutvijKothari

Comment: No it shouldn't, you are adding the 30 when you should be subtracting

Comment: @AtyFlow 13:03:00 is in 24hour format, AM/PM doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ahh yes, but the total is correct no?

Comment: in the last case Yes, but no in the fisrt and second..

Comment: @RutvijKothari i just want to see, now i have change the format.. to: format('d-m-Y H:i:s')

Comment: 13-5.5=7.5, I think the math is fine. Further, 13:03 in military time is still technically PM time, I don't think we really have a problem here.

Comment: should be 7-13 =6 ?? in complete hours plus minutes (33) @wedstrom

Comment: @AtyFlow 13:03:00 - 7:30:00 = 05:33 -> 7:30:00 + 5 hours = 12:30:00. Now, 12:30:00 + 33 minutes = 13:03:00 = 05:33. :D

Comment: OMG really thanks!  I was not doing well, I'm sorry. Thanks for your time @RutvijKothari

Comment: @AtyFlow It's okay. I was confused too. :).