# PHP TIME calc between last login (to DB )to NOW

Tags: javascript, php, wamp

I need to calc and show the minutes between 2-time stamp.
the first -> last login to the database.
the second -> current login (now).
lastTime - is the date-time of the last login - example - 2021-06-25 13:01:26

this is my code

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['pname']) && isset($_SESSION['fname']))
{
    $first = $_SESSION['pname'];
    $last = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lastTime = $_SESSION['lastTime'];

}
?>
```

Comment: You are looking for Datetime::diff -> https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP find difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688775/php-find-difference-between-two-datetimes) something like

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['pname']) && isset($_SESSION['fname'])){
    $first = $_SESSION['pname'];
    $last = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lastTime = $_SESSION['lastTime']; //2021-06-25 13:01:26
    
    $datetime1 = new DateTime();
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($lastTime);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $elapsed = $interval->format('%i minutes');
   echo $elapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use the DateTime api you can just use this code, but I would not recommand you to use it on any solution!
I would rather suggest you to use [Zachary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68131636/11523447) above.

```
<?php $lastTime = strtotime(date($_SESSION['lastTime']));
```

$currentTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$difference = $lastTime - $currentTime;

echo $difference;
?>

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_diff()` method with your dates:

```
date_diff(date_create('2020-11-11 13:00:00'),date_create('2020-11-11 13:00:00'))- 
>format("%H Hours,%M Minutes,%S Seconds");
```

Output will be :
`00 Hours,00 Minutes,00 Seconds`