# Difference Between two times Using PHP

Tags: php

I have a table that I draw information from out my DB. I want to calculate the difference between the two times in the DB

```
<?php echo abs($rows['systime']-$rows['ver_time']); ?>

<?php echo round($rows['systime']-$rows['ver_time']); ?>
```

I get no result on the above

I basically just need the minutes between the two times

Time format is HH:MM:SS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688775/php-find-difference-between-two-datetimes

Comment: @Nouphal.M Thank you it worked

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work for me pulling the info from the DB and giving difference

```
<?php
      $datetime1 = new DateTime("$rows[systime]");
      $datetime2 = new DateTime("$rows[ver_time]");
      $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
      echo $interval->format(' %H:%i:%s');
 ?>
```